# How to keep updating the TextView from onProgressUpdate after restarting the app

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity

I have started an `AsyncTask` which performs some calculation and `onProgressUpdate` updates it on text view. e.g.,

```
@Override
void doInBackground()
{
  for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
  {
    publishprogress(i);
  }
}

@Override
void onProgressUpdate(Integer.. values)
{
  text_view.setText("Value is :"+values[0]);
}
```

My issue is that After I destroy the Activity it shows in the Log that my thread and `onProgressUpdate` are still running but when I again open the App , `TextView` isn't updating.

Also, are there any alternatives to perform this? Am new to android. It would be great help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use local broadcastreceive to handler it. You can search some example about one.

Answer (score 0):

`AsynkTask` are executed under a `ThreadPoolExecutor`, if you "destroy" the `Activity` you lose the reference to your `Activity` UI, only it will be updated, to achieve this, you can use a `Service`, so since `Service`, you can check the availablelity of your `TextView`.

Good Luck.